# How to use taghelpers for not rendering server side request in form validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

When I post the following form, it requests server. How can I stop it from posting to server and validate in client side using jquery validation?

Here is my code:

```
<form asp-controller="Gigs" asp-action="Create" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
   <label asp-for="@Model.Venue"></label>
    <input asp-for="@Model.Venue" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Venue"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="@Model.Date"></label>
    <input asp-for="@Model.Date" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Date"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="@Model.Time"></label>
    <input asp-for="@Model.Time" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Time"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="@Model.Genre"></label>
    <select asp-for="@Model.Genre" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Genres, "Id", "Name"))" class="form-control"><option>Please Select One</option></select>
    <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Genre"></span>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

I tried this but didn't work

```
<environment names="Development">
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
</environment>
```

Comment: Your need `jquery-{version}.js` first and then `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` in your view or layout

Comment: There is a partial in the default template now that does this`@section Scripts {
    @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); }
}`

reference the Login.cshtml